# 440 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a toggle-style menu on a website I am developing. For some reason, I keep getting this error:

> (index):440 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Which points me to the following code:

```
theToggle.onclick = function() {
   toggleClass(this, 'on');
   return false;
}
```

The full code is:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var theToggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

    // hasClass
    function hasClass(elem, className) {
        return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
    }

    // addClass
    function addClass(elem, className) {
        if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
            elem.className += ' ' + className;
        }
    }

    // removeClass
    function removeClass(elem, className) {
        var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + '   ';
        if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
            while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0) {
                newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
            }
            elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        }
    }

    // toggleClass
    function toggleClass(elem, className) {
        var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, " ") + ' ';
        if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
            while (newClass.indexOf(" " + className + " ") >= 0) {
                newClass = newClass.replace(" " + className + " ", " ");
            }
            elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        } else {
            elem.className += ' ' + className;
        }
    }

    theToggle.onclick = function() {
        toggleClass(this, 'on');
        return false;
    }
};
```

Can anyone see what is causing this problem. I have a staging site here.

Comment: Your `theToggle` variable is null, which implies there is no element with an `id` of `toggle` available in the DOM when your page loads. Also, your `hasClass`, `addClass`, `removeClass` and `toggleClass` methods are also redundant as you can just use the `classList` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/avn3apw9/

Comment: If a function can return `null`, you need to check to ensure it's not null before using the result. Failing to check causes this to happen.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Or you should figure out why it's returning null and fix the original problem.

Comment: @Barmar Unless it returning null is a valid return value. If you're dynamically creating an element, and trying to reference it before the user causes it to be created, you'll need to handle that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's my point -- you should move the code that tries to reference it to *after* the code that creates it. An `if` statement won't make the code work, it will just prevent the error.

Comment: I added an id of "toggle" to the nav and it seemed to be working fine now. Thanks for everyones input.

Comment: What if you try to access the element in response to a button click? If both the access and creation are in response to the user, you can't necessarily expect a certain order. And my original comment was a general comment about any function that returns null as a valid value. If a function returns null, you need to check for it. It isn't always possible to ensure that a function won't return null at compile-time.

Comment: Edit: If a function returns null, *and can't be checked for correctness at compile time,* you need to check for it *at run-time*.